# What does this error mean? The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

Even though a couple people have asked this question it seems there problem is different than mine. Like most of them seem to get line numbers or the problem might be caused with ViewState.

I am using Asp.net 4.0 MVC 2.0 so I don't think I am using ViewState at all. My error does not give me line numbers are well. So I have no clue what is causing it or where in my code.

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Redirect(String url)
   at MySolutionFile.Domain.RequiresSSL.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22992379/17373 for an example of how to capture this error and ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server couldn't send the answer to the client. Network connection lost on the client could be a cause.

Not sure if closing the browser/tab at the very precise time would also give the error.

Comment: Hmm were do you think this was caused. Is there anyway I could stop this error from happening or is it something I just have to live with if this was the scenario is indeed what you think it is.

Comment: If it was what I described above, is something you have to live with. Is the nature of networking, a client may disconnect. Are you or someone else able getting this error or was it something you picked from the logs?

Comment: This is the first time I ever seen this error. ELMAH just sent me a notification about this error.

Comment: Then yes, its something you have to live with / client disconnecting can cause that at different places where asp.net writes to the response. Can't prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

We were mixing "Response.Redirect" with "return View()" that caused this issue. The browser was redirected, but we tried to still return a view...

BAD CODE

```
    switch (userType)
    {
        case "None":
            Response.Redirect("http://" + host + "/");
            break;
        default:
            Response.Redirect(internalwebhost + "/exit/");
            break;
    }

    return View();
```

BETTER CODE

```
    switch (userType)
    {
        case "None":
            url = "http://" + host + "/";
            break;
        default:
            url = internalwebhost + "/exit/";
            break;
    }

    return new RedirectResult(url);
```

Comment: A Response.End() or Flush() might solve this as well, but it is much better to return a RedirectResult