# Accepted way to prevent "The remote host closed the connection" exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, exception

I'm *constantly* getting the following exception which  is caused by a user initiating a download and it consequently failing (or being cancelled):

> Error Message : The remote host closed
>   the connection. The error code is
>   0x80072746. Stack Trace : at
>   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProcForIIS6.FlushCore(Byte[]
>   status, Byte[] header, Int32
>   keepConnected, Int32 totalBodySize,
>   Int32 numBodyFragments, IntPtr[]
>   bodyFragments, Int32[]
>   bodyFragmentLengths, Int32
>   doneWithSession, Int32 finalStatus,
>   Boolean& async) at
>   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.FlushCachedResponse(Boolean
>   isFinal) at
>   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.FlushResponse(Boolean
>   finalFlush) at

I've searched all over the internet, [and found an interesting article](http://blog.whitesites.com/fixing-The-remote-host-closed-the-connection-The-error-code-is-0x80070057__633882307305519259_blog.htm), however there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer as the best way to prevent this filling up the logs.

The user sees no error and there's no actual problem in the app as it occurs only (to my understanding) in situations out of its control (user cancelling download or loss of connection) but there has to be a way to prevent such an exception being reported.

I hate to say it but I'm tempted to check for this exception and empty catch block its ass away - but this makes me feel like a dirty programmer.

So - **what is the accepted method of preventing this exception filling up my mailbox?**

Comment: You need to explain how the user initialises download? Is it browser? Is in AJAX?...

Comment: @m.edmondson - If an exception happens then you either need to catch it or adjust your settings to NOT email you every single time this exception happens.  A download not finishing shouldn't cause this.

Comment: It's initiated via `System.Web.HttpResponse.TransmitFile()`

Comment: It's an exception. You know what you want to do when it happens. Put a try/catch around your TransmitFile call.

Comment: What would this solve?  You saying I should be placing an empty catch there (i.e. make it's problems disappear?)

Comment: I'm with John. Catch it and kill it

Comment: Yes, catch the most specific exception you can and then check the message to ensure that it's really the exception you thought. Then kill it. If it's not the exception you're expecting, then re-throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prevent a remote Host to close anything.

And in some protocols this is the normal (or at least accepted) way to say goodbye.

So you will have to handle this **specific** exception.

Comment: I understand that - I want the best/accepted/most suitable method of doing so

Comment: In this rare case an empty catch-block is acceptable. Fill it with a large comment why it's empty.

Comment: I'd like to emphasise the **this** part of the last line. Don't just catch() or catch(Exception e), catch your specific exception and let others get bubbled to the user unless you can do something about them.

Answer (score 8):

The error occurs when you try to send a response to the client but they have disconnected. You can verify this by setting a breakpoint on the Response.Redirect or wherever you are sending data to the client, wait for Visual Studio to hit the breakpoint, then cancel the request in IE (using the x in the location bar). This should cause the error to occur.

To capture the error you can use the following:

```
try
{
    Response.Redirect("~/SomePage.aspx");
    Response.End();
}
catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
{
    // Do nothing. This will happen normally after the redirect.
}
catch (System.Web.HttpException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80070057)) //Error Code = -2147024809
    {
        // Do nothing. This will happen if browser closes connection.
    }
    else
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Or in C# 6 you can use Exception filters to prevent having to re throw the error:

```
try
{
    Response.Redirect("~/SomePage.aspx");
    Response.End();
}
catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
{
    // Do nothing. This will happen normally after the redirect.
}
catch (System.Web.HttpException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80070057))
{
    // Do nothing. This will happen if browser closes connection.
}
```

Which is a better debugging experience since it will stop on the statement throwing the exception with the current state and all local variables preserved instead of on the throw inside the catch block.

Comment: And if you are working in vb.net, then ex.ErrorCode = &H80070057

Answer (score 1):

From a practical perspective, there is nothing wrong with cancelling a download by virtue of a dead computer or a killed web session, therefore catching remote host closed exceptions is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: So what would be the best way to ensure I _only_ trap this?  Check the exception message?

Comment: What does the message give you that the actual exception doesn't? Trap the exception (it may be caused my multiple reasons, but the underlying effect does not change)