# HTTPRequest The underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

I have a problem with accessing my authentication php pages from my C# .Net Applcation.

It seems to work fine on My PC, and some of my users; but my Co-Developer and around 1/3 if my users get the an error.

The error says "The underlying connection was closed" **This has been translated from french, so it might not be exact!**

My code is as follows:

```
    internal string Post(string url, string data)
    {
        string vystup = null;
        try
        {
            //Our postvars
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            //Initialisation, we use localhost, change if appliable
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebReq.KeepAlive = true;
            WebReq.Expect = "";
            //Our method is post, otherwise the buffer (postvars) would be useless
            WebReq.Method = "POST";
            //We use form contentType, for the postvars.
            WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //The length of the buffer (postvars) is used as contentlength.
            WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            //We open a stream for writing the postvars
            Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
            //Now we write, and afterwards, we close. Closing is always important!
            PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            PostData.Close();
            //Get the response handle, we have no true response yet!
            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
            //Let's show some information about the response
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

            //Now, we read the response (the string), and output it.
            Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
            vystup = _Answer.ReadToEnd();

            //Congratulations, you just requested your first POST page, you
            //can now start logging into most login forms, with your application
            //Or other examples.

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Auth Error");
        }
        return vystup.Trim() + "\n";

    }
```

The page does not output any html tags, just plain text if that helps.

Does anyone have any ideas? I can provide more information if needed!

Thanks

Comment: This looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679163/accepted-way-to-prevent-the-remote-host-closed-the-connection-exception

Comment: Sorry, but no it isn't

Comment: Did you try increasing request timeout using _WebReq.Timeout_ ?

Comment: Ive tried WebReq.Timeout=10000; still the same issue