# Exception : "The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this exception . 
I followed the suggestions given in 
[What does this error mean? The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790022/what-does-this-error-mean-the-remote-host-closed-the-connection-the-error-code/28230987#28230987)

still , I am getting the same error.

I am transferring a file from server to Client browser using `Response.WriteFile()`.

In View:

```
  $("#btnExport").on("click", function (e) {
      window.location = '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Report")';
       e.preventDefault();
  });
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public RedirectResult ExportToExcel()
{
    Download(ExportFilePath);    
    return new RedirectResult(ExportFilePath); 
}

public void Download(ExportFilePath)
{
    HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(ExportFilePath);
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename =" + ExportFileName);
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    context.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.Close();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: your `RedirectResult(ExportFilePath)` is strange a little. It should be url, where page should be redirectred, not the file path

Comment: @rock_walker : What is the suggested implementation of action where I can place Download() method.

Comment: @BhaweshPaliwal The error simply means the user closed their browser before everything was sent from the server to the client, e.g. client requests file, server starts to transfer file but before the server completes sending the file the user closes the browser.... basically there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @BhaweshPaliwal. I applied your code example at my localhost with simple *.txt file. There were no errors, I downloaded file successfully.

Comment: @BhaweshPaliwal. Looking for deeper, it maybe SignalR issue, if you utilize VS2013 and/or IIS8. Try to disable BrowserLink in VS. Sorry, I can guess only this proposal, because VS2012 and IISExpress are installed on my host.

Comment: @rock_walker Thanks for your quick observations. the solution given below perfectly worked for me with slight improvement in my code. Improvements : Instead ActionResult/RedirectResult , ContentResult OR EmptyResult worked for me.

Comment: If it works then why not its appreciated yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, you should try removing bellow lines of code

```
context.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();
context.Response.End();
```

add Bellow line

```
context.Response.TransmitFile(strFileName);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
long FileSize = myFileStream.Length;
byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
myFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
myFileStream.Close();
myFileStream.Dispose();

Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=FILENAME.jpg");

Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
Response.End();
```

let me know if above solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: Then appreciate it with by accepting this as an answered and vote +1 :)